# Setting already fetched Account Name/Login Name to Pnp Js Peoplepicker

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I am creating an edit form in spfx(with react js as a framework) where I will fetch data for particular list item using pnp js. I already fetched data from person type field say 'Sender'.Now I want to show the fetched user in peoplepicker control.

The below control is used in my code. Value for 'defaultSelectedUsers' is set statically to check whether once this control is loaded, the loginName mentioned there will pre-populate the user or not. But this attribute is not working.

Can anyone suggest how can I pre-populate this peoplepicker control?

```
<PeoplePicker
            context={this.props.context}
            titleText="Sender"
            personSelectionLimit={1}
            groupName={"some group here"} 
            showtooltip={true}
            isRequired={true}
            disabled={false}
            defaultSelectedUsers= 
            {['i:0#.f|membership|abcUser@xyz23.onmicrosoft.com']}
            selectedItems={this._getItems}
            showHiddenInUI={false}
            principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
            resolveDelay={200}
            ensureUser={true}
         />
```

Expected Behaviour: As soon as page is loaded I want the user with login Name `i:0#.f|membership|abcUser@xyz23.onmicrosoft.com` pre-populated in peoplepicker control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing R&D on this issue from 2-3 days almost.But couldn't find anything. Today I just tried a simple thing. I put email of user instead of loginName and this thing worked.

```
<PeoplePicker
        context={this.props.context}
        titleText="Sender"
        personSelectionLimit={1}
        groupName={"some group here"} 
        showtooltip={true}
        isRequired={true}
        disabled={false}
        **defaultSelectedUsers= 
        {['abcUser@xyz23.onmicrosoft.com']}**
        selectedItems={this._getItems}
        showHiddenInUI={false}
        principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
        resolveDelay={200}
        ensureUser={true}
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding ensureUser= {true} resolved the issue as follows

```
      <PeoplePicker
          context={this.props.context}
          titleText="Multi People Picker for user name"
          personSelectionLimit={5}
          groupName={""} 
          showtooltip={true}
          required={false}
          disabled={false}
          ensureUser= {true}
          onChange={this._getPeoplePickerItemsUsername}
          showHiddenInUI={false}
          principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
          resolveDelay={1000} />
```